# IDE does not recognize Jest and its functions

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, webstorm, react-native-testing-library

I have a basic react-native/expo template app. I have added `jest-expo` and `react-test-renderer` in the dev dependencies, and also have updated package.json like documented in the [expo docs for testing](https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/).

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    ...
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.2.0",
    "jest-expo": "^41.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also added `React Native Testing Library` to test the UI. And the tests are running fine.

But the problem is that WebStorm IDE is not recognizing Jest and its functions.

[image]

[image]

Could you please help me figure this out?

**Update**

As per the comments, I tried installing the Typescript Jest types definition through the Settings config and also tried installing with yarn/npm . But this didn't help.

[image]

**Another Update**

However, If I uncheck the project's node_modules libraries, the Jest type definitions picks up.

[image]

But doing so, other types of node_modules doesn't work!

Comment: can you try installing type definitions for jest ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest

Comment: @UğurEren Yes, I have tried adding @types/jest, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 5):

In Preferences - Languages & Frameworks - JavaScript - Libraries, press Download, then Select jest from the list, press Download and Install. If it didn't work try `npm i @types/jest` in your Local Folder.

Comment: Hi, I tried installing the type definition but that didn't work. However, if I uncheck the node_modules libraries the Jest types work. But doing so other node_modules types doesn't work. I have updated the question with the recent developments.

Comment: @MswTm Can you add your `.eslintrc` file to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I am not using .eslintrc

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this [WebStorm configuration](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/10/testing-with-jest-in-webstorm/#:%7E:text=WebStorm%20will%20use%20the%20template,click%20it%20and%20select%20Run.)?

> You might have noticed that some of the global Jest methods (like
> `describe` and `beforeEach`) in JavaScript files are marked as unresolved
> in the editor. To fix that, install the TypeScript type definition
> files for Jest: Go to Preferences | Languages & Frameworks |
> JavaScript | Libraries, click Download on the right-hand side of the
> dialog, then search for Jest in the list and click Install. Or add
> `@types/jest` to devDependencies in project’s package.json.

Comment: Hi, I tried installing the type definition but that didn't work. However, if I uncheck the node_modules libraries the Jest types work. But doing so other node_modules types doesn't work. I have updated the question with the recent developments.